# Magento Translation of option labels and values

Tags: localisation, option, inline-translations

I have ***6 store views for different languages***.

My problem is, `$_option['label']` and the `$_option['value']` which are using in  product-view page, cart page, cart-sidebar, onepage-chekcout is always displaying the admin-side values and not the each language value.

Can anyone help on how to get the translated versions?

Thanks

Comment: Never had problems with this using the core code, just put the content for the right store. Do you use a custom implementation or module to get the data?

Comment: There's more to the story here. When someone checks out, are they checking out in the "right" store?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create translation files for each locale.

Put them in `app/design/frontend/default/default/locale/.../translate.csv` or wherever the appropriate locale directories are.

Comment: Well, instead of using translate.csv we used Manage Options from backend and entered all the translations there, however the frontend is not displaying the correct value for the correct store view, always showing the Admin value

Answer (score 0):

As i know you should have multiple store for multi language so you can assign option label through admin store wise from attribute management like below.

catalog >> Attributes >> Manage Attribute >> open attribute >> click on Manage Label /options tab. 
After that define option label language store view wise